# How to configure TODO Highlight Extension to highlight only the comment and not entire line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have seen in some videos of content creators who use the [TODO Highlight extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wayou.vscode-todo-highlight) and it highlights all the words in the comment.

I tried to make it highlight the comment only, but it highlights the entire line.

[image]

How do I make it so that only the comment phrase is highlighted? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting called "Todohighlight: Keywords Patterns" (or `todohighlight.keywordsPattern` in the settings.JSON).  This takes in Regex as its input.

Simply set it to `TODO.*` like so:

[image: Todohighlight keywords pattern setting]

JSON:

```json
{
    "todohighlight.keywordsPattern": "TODO.*"
}
```

This should result in anything after "TODO" (which is case sensitive) to also be highlighted, thus achieving what you want.

[image]

You can tweak the Regex pattern so that it will find both lower and upper case as well (`todo.*|TODO.*` should handle both full upper and full lowercase).